# CSS - LESS class inheritance

Tags: css, less

I'm using the styles from [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#labels) and have a question about inheritance.

I'd like to make two label classes that'd inherit the label styles from bootstrap.

```
.label-new {
    .label; .label-important;
}
.label-updated {
    .label; .label-warning;
}
```

However, the above would result in LESS parse error "NameError: .label-important is undefined" because .label-important and .label-warning are defined using the following in bootstrap:

```
.label,
.badge {
  // Important (red)
  &-important         { background-color: @errorText; }
  &-important[href]   { background-color: darken(@errorText, 10%); }
  // Warnings (orange)
  &-warning           { background-color: @orange; }
  &-warning[href]     { background-color: darken(@orange, 10%); }
}
```

Is there any special syntax to inherit the .label-important/warning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that _just_ mixing in `.label` in your two new classes will give you `.lable-new-important` and `.label-new-warning` (etc.). I'm guessing you only want the `important` properties for `new` and the `warning` properties for `updated`, is that your goal?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And I'd prefer not to redefine the colors like suggested below. So it seems like a limitation of LESS unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like a functionality that would be useful. I've added another suggestion if you don't want color definitions in two places. These are the only two suggestions I have.

Answer (score 11):

I think you can only inherit the `.label` which should give `.label-new-important` and `.label-new-warning` (and equivalent for `updated`). If that is not desireable, and you want new added extensions, you probably need to define the colors again directly for the `.label` to isolate and define what you want. Like so:

```
.label { 
  // New (red) 
  &-new           { background-color: @errorText; } 
  &-new[href]     { background-color: darken(@errorText, 10%); } 
  // Updated (orange) 
  &-updated       { background-color: @orange; } 
  &-updated[href] { background-color: darken(@orange, 10%); } 
}
```

**EDIT (If you don't want to redefine the colors but use a mixin)**

To avoid a redefining of the colors, then you need to change the original definition, and do this:

First, delete the original `.label` and `.badge` definitions, and then second, define them more explicitly like so:

```
.label-important,
.badge-important {
  // Important (red)
  { background-color: @errorText; }
  { background-color: darken(@errorText, 10%); }
}

.label-warning,
.badge-warning {
  // Warnings (orange)
  { background-color: @orange; }
  { background-color: darken(@orange, 10%); }
}

.label-new {
    .label-important;
}

.label-updated {
    .label-warning;
}
```